# js поменять элемент строки местами

Tags: javascript, строки

Всех приветствую! У меня есть следующий массив ['05.01','05.02',05.03]
На выходе я должен получить  ['01.05','02.05','03.05']

Пытался использовать replace, но не совсем успешно пока.

Comment: `console.log(['05.01','05.02','05.03'].map(e=>{return e.split('.')[1]+'.'+e.split('.')[0]}))`

Answer (score 1):

С использованием `replace`

```js
let arr = ['05.01', '05.02', '05.03'].map(item => item.replace(/(\d{2}).(\d{2})/, "$2.$1"))
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант со `split` и `reverse`:

```js
const source = ['05.01','05.02','05.03'];

console.log(source.map(val => val.split('.').reverse().join('.')));
```